# Why is iteration often compulsory?

Tags: computational-physics

In any number of dynamical systems and computational approaches towards simulating e.g. fluid flow, there is an iterating component which generally converges to a fixed point (or not at all).

As a working example, take a Bayesian model-based reconstruction for a CT image. Given some initial guess and various update parameters, iterating over the system gives a posterior distribution which can become the prior for the next iterate, etc. Regularizers and whatnot put constraints on the space's shape, but iteration is still compulsory.

My question is, why is this iterating component necessary? Is this related to the general nonlinearity of function composition? Does it just make things cleaner to compute?

Comment: Unless you have an exact mathematical expression (that you can invert), iteration is a standard part of any numerical method. I'm not really clear on what the core of your question is.

Comment: Building on Jon's comment, if you don't have an exact mathematical expression, then you don't have a solution until your iteration converges to a fixed point.  Until that happens you are just guessing.

Comment: Have you considered that iteration is necessary because computers are discrete counting machine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about mathematics rather than physics.